# Can you manage two discrete forms with formset?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am a little unclear on whether two separate forms can be handled in the same view via formsets.

For example, consider these two models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
   title= models.CharField(max_length=30)
   approvers = models.ManyToManyField(
        get_user_model(), through='TaskStep')

class TaskStep(models.Model):
   approver = models.ForeignKey(
   get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   task = models.ForeignKey(Task, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Is it possible to render a single form that edits both the task model instance and associated task steps together, which I can update in a single submit?

I know I can use `inlineformset_factory` to display the `TaskStep` child options, but there isn't much [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) on it.

If I pass the following in a view:

```
def manage_tasks(request, task_id):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    TaskStepInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TaskStep, Task, exclude=('',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = TaskStepInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=task)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # etc
```

This only appear displays the `TaskStep` objects and not the parent `Task`?

Comment: Your factory is the wrong way round: `inlineformset_factory(Task, TaskStep)`. It allows you to create/update multiple `TaskStep` instances for one `Task`. But you also need add a second form to your view to edit the `Task` itself. Just have both in your view, a `TaskForm` and your `TaskStepsFormSet`, initialise them both, validate them both, and if both are valid, save them both.

Comment: Note that you should read the documentation of `modelformset`. As the docs say, `inlineformset` is just a small abstraction on top of `modelformset`, so most of the docs are above the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single view yes, but not a single form. You want a `ModelForm` to edit your `Task` and an `InlineFormSet` to edit the `TaskStep`s. The documentation builds up:

- First you need to understand how [`FormSet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)s work. This gives you a general understanding on how to render them, how the management form works and what you need to do to add or remove single forms.
- Then you want to understand [`model formsets`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets), which relate to a model (in your case `TaskStep`). That'll teach you how to save, update and delete models based on the submitted formset.
- Finally you have the inline formsets, which just link the models of the model formset to a parent. That's the doc you referenced.

One thing that's wrong in your view is the order of the models you specified. It should be:

```
inlineformset_factory(Task, TaskStep)  # TaskStep is the model being edited, Task is the parent
```

In your view, you want to create both the `TaskForm` for your `Task` and the `formset`. Both you initialise with the `task` instance and the posted data (`request.POST` and `request.FILES`) in the `POST` case.

Then you validate both, if they are both valid you can save them, if not just render the template again with the invalid forms. Just like you would do with one form.

In your template render all the forms (`task_form` and loop through all the forms in `formset`) inside **one** `<form>` tag.